# How to measure band gap of powder sample with using diffuse reflectance method

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, crystal-structure, photochemistry, spectrophotometry

We have UV SHİMADZU 2550 and its diffuse reflectance attachment. I want to measure band gap of single crystal samples. What should I do? Which formulas should I use to calculate band gap? I don't have much sample...

Answer (score 1):

It's not too hard to determine band gap.  When the energy of a wavelength of light is higher than the energy of the band gap the light will be absorbed, any wavelengths that are lower in energy will reflect or transmit. Simply make the spectrum, there should be a cliff-looking cut-off in transmittance, determine the wavelength and corresponding energy and that is your band gap.